# Default comments file and how to copy it

Tags: theme-development, comment-form

I have a custom theme. There is no comments.php file, Wordpress is using whatever the default is. I need to modify the comments area, but I want to base my changes off of the default template. Where is the default template and how can I copy it into my own theme's comments.php?

UPDATE
Sorted it out for myself. The following directory contains default fallbacks if a file is not specified in your custom theme - `\wordpress\wp-includes\theme-compat\`

I copied the comments.php file from there over to my custom theme and am ready to rock. I was told in a WordPress forum that this file is deprecated though and I should really be building my own.

Comment: So I gotta a little help from Wordpress forum. I had forgotten that I added comments to my blog by adding `comments_template( '', true );` to my single.php file. So I probably need to override some comments code to get what I want.

Comment: Please move your solution to answer (which you can accept later after bit of cooldown period) so it is in line with site's mechanics. :)

Comment: @Rarst I can't find a mark answered button. Do I need to actually submit an answer and then accept it?

Comment: yes, exactly. It's how site works so issue and solution are clearly separated. Otherwise your question will haunt us all with "unanswered" status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got some help from Wordpress forum. As of Wordpress 3.1 [a function called](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form) `comment_form()` creates the submit comment area. You can override default settings by creating an argument list and passing it in as a parameter. Here is a quick example where I change the default header **Reply** to **Comment** and then remove the **acceptable tags** section at bottom of form.

```
$comments_settings = array(                                                
    'title_reply' => 'Comment',
    'comment_notes_after' => ''
);

comment_form($comments_settings);
```